# Export not working in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Below i have pasted my example-

```
#!/bin/sh
#. /root/file.txt 
su - root -c "/bin/sh" << EOF        
if [[ -f /root/file.txt ]] ; then

. /root/file.txt 
export X=$X:/nobin  <-- not exporting correctly. Incase line no 2 is uncommented, it works.
else

echo "ERROR: /root/path.txt file is missing"
     exit 1
fi

echo "myexecutable_binary 2>&1"   
EOF

echo $?

echo "here"
```

### /root/file.txt

```
X="/usr/usr1:/usr/usr2"


export X

echo $X
```

As, i have highlighted above, export has some issue. Please help me to fix this.

Linux- Linux 2.6.18-348.el5

Comment: "export has some issue" What issue? How do you decide that export isn't working? Also, remove the loads of irrelevant junk from the code snippet.

Comment: what issue you are getting?

Comment: Line no is commented:-
 # ./new.sh
     + . /root/file.txt
     ++ X=/usr/usr1:/usr/usr2
     ++ export X
     ++ echo /usr/usr1:/usr/usr2
     /usr/usr1:/usr/usr2
     + export X=:/nobin
     + X=:/nobin
     + set +x
     binary 2>&1
     0
     here
     # vi new.sh

Comment: Un-commented line no 2:-
     # ./new.sh
     /usr/usr1:/usr/usr2
     + . /root/file.txt
     ++ X=/usr/usr1:/usr/usr2
     ++ export X
     ++ echo /usr/usr1:/usr/usr2
     /usr/usr1:/usr/usr2
     + export X=/usr/usr1:/usr/usr2:/nobin
     + X=/usr/usr1:/usr/usr2:/nobin
     + set +x
     binary 2>&1
     0
     here
     #

Comment: Difference is -> export X=/usr/usr1:/usr/usr2:/nobin.

Answer (score 0):

Your here document is being interpolated by the current shell.  I guess you have no variable `X` defined in the shell which runs this program.  I also speculate that what you actually want is for the script to not be interpolated.  A simple fix is to quote the heredoc delimiter; `<<'EOF'` with single quotes around the `EOF`.

Comment: Yes it will work, but i am facing the issue where in the block << EOF .. EOF, i have to use some variables which are already defined before. E.g- var=abc su - root -c "/bin/sh" << 'EOF' echo $var EOF - will not print abc. Hence, 'EOF' or "EOF" will not work.

Comment: Then backslash those dollar signs which should not be immediately expanded.

Comment: Your question really should explain your requirements, both the ones which were merely implied but not properly explained, and these additional ones which were not even hinted at in the question.